# Having trouble toggling state with dynamic key value pair

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a nested sidebar menu using json to denote the structure of navigation. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get past this nagging error of

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item3' of null. ('Item3' is from my json below).

I feel like I'm doing something wrong with setting the state dynamically for menu items that have children, however, I'm doing exactly what's being done in other examples I've read. Specifically, I think this.state[menuItem.name] is causing an issue because initially there is no value associated with it. When I comment out any lines regarding state[menuItem.name], the issue goes away. Also the json is being read just fine when I debugged it.

This is the example I followed: https://medium.com/@vayamjain/making-a-nested-sidebar-menu-in-react-f8595031995e

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import menuItems from './menuItems.json'
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import ExpandLess from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess'
import ExpandMore from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore'
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'


const styles = theme => ({
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
})


export class SideBarMenu extends Component {

  handleClick = item => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({[item]: !prevState[item]}))
  }


  handleMenuRender = items => {
     items.map(menuItem => {
      console.log(menuItem.name)
      if (!menuItem.children) {
        return (
          <div key={menuItem.name}>
            <ListItem button key={menuItem.name}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {<menuItem.icon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText inset primary={menuItem.name} />
            </ListItem>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return (
        <div key={menuItem.name}>
          <ListItem button key={menuItem.name} >
            <ListItemIcon>
              {<menuItem.icon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText inset primary={menuItem.name} />
            {this.state[menuItem.name] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore /> }
            <Collapse in={menuItem.name} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              {this.handleMenuRender(menuItem.children)}
            </Collapse>
          </ListItem>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={this.props.isDrawerOpen}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
            <IconButton onClick={this.props.handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />

          <List>
            {this.handleMenuRender(menuItems.data)}
          </List>

        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(SideBarMenu);
```

And the json that I'm reading:

```
{
    "data" : [
      {
          "name": "Item1",
          "url": "/item1",
          "icon": "MailIcon"
      },
      {
        "name": "Item2",
        "url": "/item2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Item3",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Child31",
            "url": "/child31"
          },
          {
            "name": "Child32",
            "url": "/child32"
          },
          {
            "name": "Child32",
            "url": "/child32"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Item4",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Child41",
            "url": "/child41"
          },
          {
            "name": "Child42",
            "url": "/child42"
          },
          {
            "name": "Child43",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Child431",
                "url": "/child431"
              },
              {
                "name": "Child432",
                "url": "/child432,"
              },
              {
                "name": "Child433",
                "url": "/child433"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Truly stuck on this one, any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: where is your state initialized ? it would make sense that `this.state[menuItem.name]` fails because there isn't any

Comment: First of all `<menuItem.icon />` will return undefined because of conditions in your if statement and also why would you call `<menuItem.icon />` like component if it is just JSON property?